# Mac can access Samba folder on CentOS but can't read anything

Tags: centos, samba, macintosh

On Mac, used finder - go - connect to server to connect Mac to the Samba on CentOs.

I connect with Linux user name and password. Then the home directory appears. The issue is that all files show up but can't copy or read them.

Mac complains there is no permission.

Confused and not sure how to solve it?!

any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the selinux Boolean to allow samba to use home directories?  It is set with:

```
setsebool -P samba_enable_home_dirs 1
```